# Azure WebApp not accepting larger JSON payload

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I have a ASP.NET Core 2.1 WebAPI project hosted in Azure as a Windows App Service in Premium Tier.

This API has an endpoint that accepts a POST request with a JSON payload (Content-Tye=application/json).

When I call this API(from Postman or from C# console app using HttpClient) and pass a JSON payload of 100KB then it gives error **"an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"**.
But when I call this same API with a smaller JSON payload like 20KB then it succeeds.

So is there any settings to increase request length in Azure WebApp?

Answer (score 0):

> Starting in ASP.NET Core 2.0.0, both Kestrel and HttpSys will be enforcing a a 30MB (~28.6 MiB) max request body size limit.
>
> If the request body size exceeds the configured max request body size limit, the call to Request.Body.ReadAsync will throw an IOException. If this exception is uncaught, Kestrel will respond with a 413 Payload Too Large response and HttpSys will respond with a generic 500 Internal Server Error response.
>
> This limit can be changed either globally or on a per-request basis, and is disabled for Kestrel running behind IIS where the normal web.config limit still applies.

From https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/267